# library in c# to compose an image using layers/masks/filters

Tags: c#, image, api, generator

I am looking for some sort of API similar to Photoshop functionality, I need to create an image using layers/masks/filters programmatically.

An example: I know how to make a nice button in Photoshop, there is a sequence of simple actions. What I want is to automate this process and generate an image of the button on the fly with a few input parameters.

I think I am not the first one who came up with such idea, there must be some library out there that does this thing. Unfortunately I cannot find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You failed to mention if the library needs to be free/open source or if commercial libraries are acceptable but one of the best out there is [GdPicture.NET](http://www.gdpicture.com/products/dotnet/document-imaging-sdk.php?gclid=CL_Uh-LK-aYCFQYnbAodRUkLEA). I doubt you'll find anything free that is remotely comprehensive but a good free one is [Filters](http://filters.sourceforge.net/) library (LGPL).

Comment: this one looks good, unfortunately it doesn't do layers or masks, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is an API like this

but there is free open source software which is Paint.net

get it here

http://www.getpaint.net/download.html

see source code here 
http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source_codes/paint.net.cfm

hope it helped

Comment: yep, I thought about that, it seems to be an overkill though, but as the only option I think I'll take it

Answer (score 0):

[GDI+ in .NET](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22GDI%2B%22+.NET)?

Comment: GDI is a too low-level API, there is no abstraction for layer and mask

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't used them you could take a look at:
Emgu CV: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Emgu_CV
or OpenCvSharp : http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) have layers support http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/ and there is [Net wrapper](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php?ImageMagick=43uv0q2880nko2donps3flfe27#dot-net)